# Avoiding pseudorandom number generation in R

Tags: r, random

How can I randomly sample n integers (let's say from 1 to 200) avoiding the pseudorandom problem? I'm currently using `sample()`, but the sequence generated is the same every time I run my code.

Comment: Have you used `set.seed` anywhere in your script?

Comment: We don't have your code so we have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Having not seen your code, it sounds like you are (unintentionally) reseeding the RNG. At any rate, if you are interested in avoiding any possible issues that stem from PRNGs you can use the [`random` package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/random.html), which utilizes random.org's *true* random number generator. For example,

```
set.seed(123)
R> random::randomNumbers(10, 1, 200, col = 1)
#       V1
# [1,] 178
# [2,] 171
# [3,]  20
# [4,]  47
# [5,] 113
# [6,]  75
# [7,] 120
# [8,] 125
# [9,]  98
# [10,]  15

set.seed(123)
R> random::randomNumbers(10, 1, 200, col = 1)
#       V1
# [1,] 112
# [2,]  84
# [3,]  83
# [4,]  20
# [5,]  19
# [6,] 112
# [7,]  64
# [8,] 134
# [9,] 105
# [10,]  63
```

---

Comment: Didn't know about this package.  (+1)